# How to use useState in other functions React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have a question about react native. I want to write a username in the textInput here

```js
function logIn({ navigation }) {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  return (
    <View  style={{ backgroundColor: "white"}} >
      <View>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}  placeholder='username' placeholderTextColor='white' textAlign='center' onChangeText={(val) => setUsername(val)} />
      </View>
      <View>
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and then I want to see the username i wrote on this screen. Of course this doesnt work because it shows Cant find variable username so is there a way to fix this?

```js
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Welcome {username}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You colud pass parameters to `Home` screen using `navigation.navigate` function in this way:

```
function logIn({ navigation }) {
  
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  return (
    <View  style={{ backgroundColor: "white"}} >
      <View>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}  placeholder='username' placeholderTextColor='white' textAlign='center' onChangeText={(val) => setUsername(val)} />
      </View>
      <View>
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', {username: username})} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then in `HomeScreen`:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Welcome {route.params.username}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you I forgot about this. I already fixed it with route :)

Comment: and what happens when you go to another screen and come back to the home screen? I assume `username` would be undefined, unless of course you pass `username` between every navigation, which would be far from ideal?

Comment: @andymccullough Your answer/suggestion is in general true. My answer is more oriented to what OP asked.

Comment: Its not really a solution though if it works in one specific case but will fail in many other trivial and expected scenarios

Comment: @andymccullough I repeat: this is not a complete solution: it's just an answer to what OP asked. That's it. This site is full of "partial" solutions (I mean solutions that could be not applicable to all scenarios).

Answer (score 4):

You need to structure your state in a way that it is accessible to the components that need it.  React likes you to have state in a component thats 'higher' in the tree than the components that need it, you can look at https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html for this.

Otherwise you could use the `Context` API or a 'global' store like Redux.

Logged in user data is a good candidate for the likes of Context or Redux, that way you will have access to the likes of `username` in any part of the application that is within your Context / Redux provider that *provides* the logged in data (or whatever other *global* data you may have)